# LinkButton postback but click event not fired

Tags: c#, .net, linkbutton

Hi everyone
This is my first post on stackoverflow (which btw is by far my favourite site for finding answers). After finally admitting defeat, I'm hoping someone can help me with this problem...

The question has already been asked several times, but none of the suggested solutions I found has helped. Apologies in advance for a lengthy post, but I want to avoid anyone wasting their time on suggesting things I tried already.

The code below worked until recently, and its structure has not been touched since (although unrelated changes were made to the child page). In any event, it suddenly stopped working. Now even the most simplified button won’t fire.

**Setup**

- VS 2008 C#, IIS 7 (no changes in setup since way before it stopped working)
- nested masterpage (main + 1 child)
- dynamically loaded ucl with datalist in child page
  (i.e. MP => nested MP => child page => ucl => datalist => linkbutton)
- linkbutton click event also resides in ucl

**Problem**

On LB click, the postback occurs ok, but the server-side click event never gets hit.

**Code**

page:

```
var ctrlX = base.LoadControl("~/somedir/someucl.ascx");

=> loads fine
```

ascx file (datalist stripped of all but the button):

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlX" RepeatLayout="Table" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnX" OnClick="btnX_Click" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>               
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void btnX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// do something  
}
```

**things tried**

- cleaning the solution
- digging out a working backup and checking for code changes 
   
  (found none affecting the structure or user control)
- setting LinkButton CausesValidation true/false
- stripping datalist and LinkButton down to bare essentials
- adding AddressOf="btnX.click" to LinkButton
- wrapping UpdatePanel one at a time with varying settings around
   usercontrol  
   datalist  
   linkbutton
- reattaching eventhandler in usercontrol init / load event:

  ```
  IEnumerable<Control> controls = Utils.FlattenChildren(dlX);

  foreach (var button in controls.OfType(LinkButton)())
  {
      if (button.ID.Contains("btnX"))
          button.Click += new EventHandler(btnX_Click);
  }
  ```

  Wherever I add above code, all buttons are found and the event is attached, but click event doesn't fire ((LinkButton) = LinkButton inside <>; couldn't get it to display right, still struggling a bit with the editor)
  .
- adding PostBackUrl manually in page load event
- comparing the client ids between load/postback events
  => they always match

That's it. Right now, I can't think of what else to try or check (maybe something in the breakpoint context menu on postback?).

Because the ucl loads fine, and the postback is working ok, I suspect the problem is somewhere in the ucl, rather than the child page loading it. But maybe not.

If at all possible, I want to avoid workarounds (I need the button command argument, not shown above, and am not keen on solutions such as jquery with hidden field or query string).

Apart from anything, I would really like to understand what causes this.

Obviously, I'm missing something... Thanks to anyone taking their time reading/helping with this!

**======== as requested additional codebehind =======**
I've simplified the parent page code to a minimum, dropping all method calls, and as per Eoins suggestion moved the ucl load in the page's init event. The ucl code remains as shown above. The DL and LB show up fine, and on click the postback is triggered, ucl page load event is hit, but as before, the server click event is not hit.

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrlX = base.LoadControl("~/someucl.ascx");

        if (ctrlX == null)
            return;

        DataList dlX = (DataList)ctrlX.FindControl("dlX");

        if (dlX == null)
            return;

        DummyCollection x = new DummyCollection();

        x.Add(null); // ok since the test LB does not draw on the datasource
        dlX.DataSource = x;
        dlX.DataBind();
        pnlX.Controls.Add(ctrlX);

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

Comment: SO are you using VB.NET or C#? When do you add your control to the tree?

Comment: When is your `Repeater`-instance bound? On every request, or auto-binding, at which life-cycle-step? When is the adding of the control done?

Comment: @bash.d: see my 1st bullet under setup (VS 2008 C#, IIS 7)

Comment: the ucl is loaded on every page's page load event; the datalist resides permanently in the ucl, i.e. is not loaded dynamically

Comment: I wasn't sure, because you are using funny things like `AddressOf` and `<>` in your bullet-lists, this is not C#!

Comment: AddressOf was a suggested solution in another post, an act of desperation on my part really; the <> contained the word 'LinkButton' and are part of TypeOf(); that's perfectly valid in C#, I just couldn't get it to display properly in the stackoverflow editor, which just dropped it completely (perhaps mistaking it for a html tag) - so I replaced it with rounded brackets (there's probably a proper way in the editor I just haven't found yet)

Comment: Try disabling View State.

Comment: thanks, I tried it but no luck; your comment prompted me to also investigate ControlState, but I'm not so familiar with it, so no joy there either yet

Comment: @Kta: somehow it had something to do with ViewState after all; when I disabled it on usercontrol level it worked (previously, I'd done it on page level); curiously, the whole thing now works again after re-enabling ViewState (so essentially, it's all back to how it was all along, perhaps the application just had a hiccup); I don't see a way to mark a comment as answer, but if you re-post it, I'll vote for it

Comment: Those problems usually occur because ViewState of the controls are not loaded correctly. I wasted weeks to solve it but no luck and there isn't a single working example about it. Now when I need to use dynamically loaded controls I always disable ViewState and use HiddenFields instead. Upvote would be sufficient :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var ctrlX = base.LoadControl("~/somedir/someucl.ascx");
```

Where exactly does this code live on your page?

You'll need to make sure you're creating it and adding it to the control collection early enough in the page lifecycle so that on subsequent postbacks its created & wired up in time. I.e. in the oninit event.

```
protected override OnInit(...)
{
   base.OnInit(...);

   var ctrlX = base.LoadControl("~/somedir/someucl.ascx");

   this.Controls.Add(ctrlX);
}
```

Comment: also, binding as to be done properly ... and using the same ids again ... and and and ... correct life-cycle-step is just a single-shot ...

Comment: agreed... but it's the one I find bites people most often with Dynamic Control instantiation... if nothing else (since his link button is within the control and the event is declaritively placed on that linkbutton) it's a good starting place to check.

@DarthVader - post more code so we can see what's going on it your pages code behind

Comment: the user control is loaded in the pages page load event, which fires before the ucl page load event (is that still too late?); in both ucl init and load event the buttons are present on postback; the button ids are always the same, and as said, I checked them on postback and they don't change

Comment: @eoin: I'll give loading the ucl in the parent page init event a try, although it still wouldn't explain to me why it worked for quite some time

Comment: @eoin: sadly, it did not help :-( I added some additional code in the original post